# How do I change the font color of the selection list in a spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I've created a spinner, from where a user can select a value. I CAN change the textcolor of the spinner itself like shown in this picture:

[image]

Unfortunately when I press the spinner a list of items, to be selected, is shown, but these have a white font color on white background, and I just haven't been able to change this: [image]

I've googled the problem and others have experienced the same problem. None of the fixes suggested worked for me.
As far as I understand I have to make a custom list of some kind, but well.. I'm not able to make it work. Any suggestions?

My code looks like this (array_spinner is a array of strings):

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row, array_spinner);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

And my row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerText" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:textSize="14dp" />
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this (untested). I'm basically reproducing `simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml` but with a black text color:

- Replace the line

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row, array_spinner);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

with

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row, array_spinner);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
```

- Add this file in `res/layout`, called `spinner_dropdown_item.xml`:

```
<CheckedTextView 
  android:id="@android:id/text1" 
  style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle" 
  android:singleLine="true" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
  android:textColor="#FF000000"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly fine! 
Thanks for the very useful and fast answer :)

Answer (score 6):

Simple and Crisp

```
private OnItemSelectedListener your_spinner _name = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                               long id) {
        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLUE); 
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue. My answer isn't the most proper answer, but it's a very quick solution for those using a basic app theme.

If you are creating the arrayadapter for the spinner using

```
createfromResource()
```

Do NOT use getApplicationContext(). Declare Myclass.this instead. My text now stays the same as the basic app theme. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: Same problem here, TY